# Customize price with currency switcher magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.4

Hi I need some customization with price module in magento 2.2.x version.
I have setup 2 product currency USD and EUR, default currency is USD if an product have $100 USD and if I will change the price currency from USD to EUR and if  Standard Conversion rate to Euros is 1.16547 then price of product will be 85.80 Euro but I need to add 10% price extra that means it should be approx 94.30.
Hope it does make sense can anyone help how Can I customize it so product price will be change everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fix the conversion rates, then you can fill the custom conversion rates from **`Stores`** > **`Currency (Currency Rates)`**.

If you want to customize the conversion rates imported by currency conversion API, then you need to modify the code of **`Magento_Directory`** module.

I hope that it makes sense.

Comment: I am not changing the conversion rates I just want to change the product price by adding some extra value after change the currency at front end for customers

Comment: Then you need to modify it by overriding Magento_Directory module.